# Should I go for WCF or simply Razor/cshtml file for creating services?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, razor, webforms, asp.net-webpages

I've got an old web forms that is to be extended with some ajax functionality. I've upgraded to .net 4, but wondering what approach to go for when creating new services.

I don't have to much experience with writing wcf services, and it seems way much simpler just writing a the service using a simple cshtml file like this:

```
@{    
    var db = Database.Open("MyConnectionString); 
    var data = db.Query("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Col1 = @0", '123');
    Json.Write( new { results=data}, Response.Output);
}
```

What are the pitfalls using this strategy compared to creating a wcf service?

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment to CodeCaster, I think you're confusing the concepts of web service and web method.  If all you're doing is adding Ajax to your app, then you want web methods, which are action methods that return json.  And, since you're using webpages, then your approach is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, and yes, you're right about me confusing conceptes and I guess I'm also also comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 0):

Using WCF, you could do:

```
[OperationContract]
public UserNow GetCurrentUser()
{
    string UserName = Membership.GetUser().UserName; 
    string UserToView = Request.Params["UserToView"];
    //do a bunch of things.
    return UserNow;
}
```

The advantages?

- It's strongly typed (you can't return a string or boolean or new FooBar() or just nothing at all, while you can `Response.Write` all or nothing you like)
- A WSDL is generated, which clients can consume so they'll know what operations they can execute and what data types are sent
- Using WCF, you can easily add another binding to support another range of clients (basicHttp and wsHttp for webservices, netTcp for communicating more efficiently with other clients written in .NET) while you don't have to change any of your code

And there are probably a ton of other things I'd forget.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. Yes, agree with all of the advantages, but in my case the context is an existing web app, no new clients - I just want to do some quick changes for a more ajax style app. I updated the sample to better show the advantages with a non-strong typing approach.

Comment: @Larsi as with Mystere Man's answer, in this case, given the conditions, your approach is a perfectly valid one.

Answer (score 0):

One consideration not mentioned in the other responses is the performance of Json.Write. It works well for small record sets w/ a few columns, but I've noticed that it is appreciably slow w/ **even as few as ~70 records and 10 columns**. This is especially important in the context of a web application that you are "Ajaxifying" where you typically are trying to make the application more responsive to user interactions. In these cases I'll typically use Json.Write just to get a proof of concept working, but then will end up going back and modifying the razor page to loop through the returned records and building the JSON string w/ a StringBuilder and write that to the output.

I don't know the performance of WCF, but if it's faster than looping a string builder, you might add that to the list of benefits above (to be weighed against the complexity of setting it up).

Comment: I have also seen that it is slow. Was not sure if it was a problem on my pc. Thanks for your comments.